# Reading automatically generated documentation for DOLFIN c++ library

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the documentation of the DOLFIN c++ library for finite element modelling located on this link:

https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin/1.3.0/python/programmers-reference/index.html

but the documentation is hard to read, so for someone without c++ knowledge how you will read the following specification of parameters for the c++ method eval_cell() of the Expression class (https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/2017.2.0/python/programmers-reference/cpp/function/Expression.html):

Parameters:

```
double > & values (Array<) – (Array<double>) The values at the point.
Array< double > & x (const) – (Array<double>) The coordinates of the point.
ufc::cell & cell (const) – (ufc::cell) The cell which contains the given point.
```

Comment: It makes no sense for someone with C++ knowledge either. This looks like some horribly botched tool output. As if you used a python doc tool to parse C++ signatures.

Comment: The first line is definitely not right.
Is the part before the minus the function declaration and the part after the minus some kind of comment?

Comment: It would be helpful if you link the original source. I guess it is from here: [dolfin.cpp module](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/2017.2.0/python/programmers-reference/cpp/function/MultiMeshFunction.html). And based on that the assumption of @MaxLanghof about the python doc tool is really likely.

Comment: @MartinMorterol I didn't downvote, but the reason might be that the original source was not linked. Without out that the shown "docs" don't make much sense, and not possible to answer. But then it should have been a question for clarification instead of a downvote, but on the other hand there is still no response from the OP according to that.

Comment: Thank you all for your help I will modify the question to point to the link of the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a look at [the page t.niese linked in the comments](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/2017.2.0/python/programmers-reference/cpp/function/MultiMeshFunction.html) I think this is a automatically generated documentation, with a really bad generator (like really really bad).

So, if we fix the butchered first line, realign some braces here and there and fix the position of const it might become clearer:

## Parameters

- `const Array<double>& values`<sup>1</sup> – The values at the point.
- `const Array<double> &x` – The coordinates of the point.
- `const ufc::cell &cell` – The cell which contains the given point.

## Meaning

You are dealing with a function that takes three parameters, the first and second are of type `Array<double>`, which seems to be generic container. The third parameter is of type `ufc::cell`, whatever this is. All three parameters are passed by reference (see the `&` before each variable name) and not by value. But they are not just passed as reference but actually as const reference (see the `const`), meaning that the function can't modify the objects you give to it.

I can't however say much about the comments for each parameter.

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume the first parameter is also const, because it got the brackets, where the `const` is noted in the other two parameters, but this is just guessing.